# How to use a monospaced font in Puzzling questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

What are the ways to use a monospaced font in a Puzzling StackExchange question?  If there are multiple ways, is there a preferred way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Code block font` is monospaced and probably the most common form across the network.

You can add it with a ` before and after your text.

```
You can also prefomat text
by adding 4 spaces before it
```

There is also the less common $\mathtt{mathjax}\ \mathtt{typewriter}\ \mathtt{font}$ which is also monospaced, but a bit of a hassle to implement. You can add this with `$\mathtt{}$` and add your text in between the curly brackets, but this won't add spaces.

Overall, I would recommend the code block option, as this is most common

---

(In reply to comment:)

```
ABCDE
X Y Z
```

or

`ABCDE`
`X Y Z`

Comment: Thanks.  The code block font gives me a monospaced font but it won’t work well for multiple lines of text.  I want to have the i-th character of each line to be lined up vertically.  As an example, if I have ABCDE on the first line and X Y Z on the second line, I want the C&Y to be aligned as well as the E&Z.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson you can still do that, edited it in!

Comment: Your revised answer works for me.

Comment: Note: standard screen readers will struggle to read either code or MathJax, so please do not use this font as simple decoration - it causes accessibility problems.

Comment: @bobble Who said I was going to use this information for simple decoration?  You seem so quick to judge people.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson I never said that -  just that *if* it's going to be simple decoration, don't do it. The comment is addressed at anyone who generally stumbles across this answer. If what you're doing is not simple decoration my comment doesn't apply. Please don't interpret things as personal attacks when they were not aimed at you.